# extjs combobox triger only after text type but not on click

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs6, extjs6-modern

here is my code

```
                     {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        minChars: 3,
                        anchor: '100%',
                        fieldLabel: 'Type',
                        name: 'typeName',
                        typeAhead: true,
                        mode: 'remote',  
                        emptyText: 'Select Type',
                        valueField: 'id',
                        bind: {
                            store: '{type}'
                        }
                    },
```

so I have combobox whos store is autoLoad:true,
but when i click on the combobox button, it resend the request to server. i dont want that , i want to send the request to server only when someone type something in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
                  {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    minChars: 3,
                    anchor: '100%',
                    fieldLabel: 'Type',
                    name: 'typeName',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    mode: 'remote',  
                    emptyText: 'Select Type',
                    valueField: 'id',
                    bind: {
                        store: '{type}'
                    },
                    triggerAction : 'all',
                    queryMode     : 'local',
                    listeners: {
                      change: function (field, newValue, oldValue) {
                        var store = field.getStore(),
                            rec =store.findRecord('id',newValue);
                        if(Ext.isEmpty(rec)){
                            // You can write the code to send the request to server.
                         }                         
                    }
                   }
                }
```

I have added two config property in you combobox:

```
triggerAction : 'all',
queryMode     : 'local'
```

Now when you will write something in your combobox then change event fired.

`change` event also fired when you select any dropdown item. So you can check it that changed value is new written value or already selected from dorpdown items.